# Jquery - Run on client whilst Apache server reloads?

Tags: php, jquery, apache

I have a simple php page that has a button on it. When the button is clicked the Apache server is reloaded. This is intended and works as expected.

When the button is pressed is there any way I can wait for 10 seconds and then display 'Apache Reloaded' ? or as the server has been reloaded will that kill what the client is doing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you bind an event to your button in this case to the id #button

Then you call the check object method, `ajax_check.reload_apache();` which will start ajax method that will send the request to your url ( that will restart apache ), upon success it will fire Bridge method that it will be looping ajax requests ( to a different url because we don't want to keep reloading apache ) every 5 seconds with a maximum of 5 tries. ( you can change this numbers in your constructor ).

ps: you need jquery and of course it still needs a little bit more validation, but it should fit your needs.

```
function check() {
    this.max_errors = 5; // maximum of tries
    this.timeout = 5000; // 5 seconds delay in every request
    this.url = 'test22'; // url to reload apache ( script url w/e )
    this.url_check = 'index'; // any url from your webserver, so you can check if its up
    this.status = 0;  // don't change
    this.interval = 0; // don't change
    this.errors = 0;  // don't change
    this.flag_first = 0;  // don't change
}

check.prototype = {
    constructor: check,
    ajax: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            // if first call use self.url to reload apache
            // if requesting for server alive use the url_check
            url: (self.flag_first == 1) ? self.url_check : self.url 
        }).done(function() {

          if(self.flag_first == 1){
                self.status = 1;
                window.clearInterval(self.interval);
                console.log('Apache Reloaded');
          }else{
              // RUNS for the first time
              self.flag_first = 1;
              self.bridge();
          } 

        }).fail(function(){
           if(self.flag_first == 1){
             self.errors++;

             if(self.errors >= self.max_errors){ // if errors are higher or equal to max_errors
                alert('Stopped');
                window.clearInterval(self.interval);
                self.errors = 0; // reset errors
             }
            }
        });
    },
    bridge: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.interval = window.setInterval(function() {
            self.ajax();
        }, self.timeout);
    },
    reload_apache: function(){
        this.ajax();
    }
};

var ajax_check = new check();

$('#button').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   ajax_check.reload_apache();
});
```

Comment: What if the restart takes more than 10 seconds?

Comment: let me change my awnser, i misunderstanding ur needs

Comment: Ps: don't forget to still bind your button with a preventDefault anyway.

Comment: Sorry How do I use this ? I'm not sure what I need to do to use this code. Thx

Comment: Hi I'll be testing this shortly and will post back. Thanks

Comment: Not had a chance to try this, but have sort of found a way around it. Before the reload I capture the Apache pid, I then reload wait 5 seconds and capture the pid again. If the pids don't match and the new pid is not blank, then Apache has been restarted.

Comment: Only issue I've found is following the apache restart I have to reload the page for the buttons on the page to work again. Only have this issue in IE, chrome, Firefox and safari are fine.

Comment: If you could share your html and javascript code, would be easier to help you out.

Comment: Looks like this may have been a caching issue in IE. I've added cache:false to my ajax request and added some HTML headers to help stop caching.. Seems to working. I'm going to accept your answer as it appears to be a more through solution.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I do not know exactly what you mean with "reload server", if that actually reloads the page, anything you specify after that call (to reload the page) will not be executed.

If you do not reload the page:

You can use Jquery [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function to output things with a delay, although it's mostly used for effects.

What I usually use is [javascript timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout), when it's more about text and such.

Comment: If you have a function on your back-end code that reloads the server and starts your page again you could pass a message saying "Server reloaded", implementation depends on how you do the server reload.

Comment: Hi. The button is calling a script that reloads the Apache Server.

Comment: Script where? Javascript or some kind of server side script?

Comment: Server side script. Its a simple bash script.

Answer (score 0):

I will use pseudo-code, but this can easily be written in JavaScript or jQuery

```
On button click: 

    Send restart request with ajax

    Show "Server is restarting" in an overlay for example

    Do: 
       - wait 2 seconds
    While (dummy ajax request fails)

    Replace "Server is restarting" with "Server restart complete"
```